# Highest number of ranges that have common intersection

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, range, intersection

I'm facing problem, where I need to find the highest number of the ranges that have common intersection. But I'm not able to find any good solution.

If we have for example these ranges:

`<0, 4>`

`<2, 6>`

`<4, 6>`

So in this case all sets have one common intersection and it's

`<4, 4>`

Is there a way how to find this in C++??

Comment: I don't think there will be any direct implementation available to it in c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create struct that holds the coodinate and either it is beginning or end of the range.
2. Create an array (vector) of the struct and let it hold all beginning and end of input ranges.
3. Sort the array in ascending order of the coodinate. beginning should come before end if they have the same coodinates.
4. Initialize `score` to zero.
5. Iterate the sorted array from the head to the tail. If the element is beginning, increment the `score`. If the element is end, decrement the `score`.
6. The answer will be the maximum value of `score` throughout the iteration.

Example:

For the input `<0, 4>, <2, 6>, <4, 6>`, there are 6 events:

```
0 begin
4 end
2 begin
6 end
4 begin
6 end
```

the sorting arranges these events like this:

```
0 begin
2 begin
4 begin
4 end
6 end
6 end
```

then calculate the score:

```
initial : score = 0
0 begin : score = 1
2 begin : score = 2
4 begin : score = 3
4 end   : score = 2
6 end   : score = 1
6 end   : score = 0
```

Now you know that the answer is 3,.